# How to collaborate with another developer when using watson conversation?

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-conversation

I created a new bluemix account and am setting up a watson conversation with intents, entities and dialogs.  How can I work with another engineer on the same project?  Is there a "shared" project concept where we can both log and and update things?

How do multiple engineers in general work on watson conversation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the latest UI in bluemix, click on your name/icon on the top right. In the sidebar that opens up you will find "Manage Organisations".

Select your workspace, and "Team Directory". There you can add your co-worker to get access.

You can work on conversation at the same time, but I would recommend not to work in the same areas, as you may not see their changes straight away.